# Structured Streaming - java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found

Tags: azure, databricks

We've recently started with structured streaming on azure data-bricks.
Currently we're consuming events from event hubs and writing them on to azure datalake store as parquet.

I'm able to write the streams onto console, but encountering error when we try writing them onto any physical storage (Blob/Azure Datalake) "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found:"

```
    val schema = new StructType()
                      .add("col1",StringType, nullable = true)
                      .add("col2", StringType, nullable = true)
                      .add("col3", StringType, nullable = true)
                      .add("col4",StringType, nullable = true)


val messages = incomingStream.selectExpr("offset","partitionKey","cast (body as string) AS Content")
val structuredMsg = messages.select($"offset",$"partitionKey",from_json(col("Content"),schema).alias("data"))

val results = structuredMsg.
select($"offset",$"partitionKey",current_date().as("date_1"),$"data.col1".as("col1"),$"data.col2".as("col2"),$"data.col3".as("col3"),$"data.col4".as("col4"))

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}

results.
  withColumn("date", $"date_1").
  writeStream.
  format("text"). // write as Parquet partitioned by date
  partitionBy("date").
  option("path", "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/XXX-databricks-mount/XXX-databricks/test").
  option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/checkpoint_path/").
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(60.seconds)).
  outputMode(OutputMode.Append).
  start




java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: {"ehName":"test1","partitionId":1}
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource$$anonfun$getBatch$2.apply(EventHubsSource.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource$$anonfun$getBatch$2.apply(EventHubsSource.scala:231)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:137)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.getBatch(EventHubsSource.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:394)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:390)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigned sparkSession checkpoint path separately from the writeStream statement and the code worked.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/checkpoint_path/");

results.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("csv").option("path", "dbfs:/mnt/datalake/XXX-databricks-mount/XXX-databricks/test").start().awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using the same checkpoint location for multiple streaming jobs. One stream started started writing and the other one tried to read it and interpret the entries which will result in an error.

I had the same Issue reading from 2 eventhubs and using the same checkpoint location, which resulted in my second job to try to read from a non existing topic/partition combination.